# redux-saga subscribe workers conditionally depending on UI component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a global common UI button component (`<ButtonRefresh />`) that is present in a base UI component `<ApplicationBase />`. Lets say I have children components inside ApplicationBase which are rendered depending on route like: `HomePage`, `UserDetailPage`, `ProductsPage` and `ProductDetailPage` etc. 
Inside these pages can be any number of other components such as `UserEntity`, `ProductEntity`, `ProductEntityList` etc.

All these components should be able to implement their own data retrieve/display logic.

When the refresh button is clicked it dispatches an action: `APP_REFRESH`. I have a redux-saga that watches for this action and does some background work (network calls):

`function* appRefreshWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery(APP_REFRESH, appRefreshWorker);
}`

My problem is that the background work that needs to be done is dependent on which ever child components are currently mounted. I don't want to reload data or update entities that are not being displayed.

**Ideally each component would be able to listen for the `APP_REFRESH` action and run its own refresh worker saga - *but only when mounted*.**

How can I go about 'refreshing' only components that are active (mounted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the approaches taken with the `react-boilerplate` repo? https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

You can dynamic inject (and eject) sagas alongside components using a `withSaga` approach.  The sagas are injected and ejected from the store when a component mounts or unmounts.  Its a similar approach to `withReducer` from `recompose`.  Example in repo: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/HomePage/index.js#L132

Check out the injection implementation: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/utils/injectSaga.js#L28 . Specifically the `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` methods on the HOC.

I think you can accomplish what your looking for with this functional programming approach.

Comment: Thanks this is the sort of thing I'm after and should be able to cover my use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-redux-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) to keep data about the current route in the store.

Then you can [select](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#selectselector-args) that data in your `appRefreshWorker` to conditionally refresh data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That solution could work however it requires manual definition of all the route states and components combinations. I'm looking for a more flexible solution where each individual component can manage itself independent of route.

Comment: Ideally, you need a list of the active components in your store. If you don't want to explicitly define the route/component relations, you could dispatch an action from the child component when it is mounted. Then reduce these actions into a list of active components